# Mock System.class per method in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am facing issue to get the `System.getProperty("name")` value per method vise after mocking `System.class`
Example:

```
@Test
public void Test1()throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
    // Configuration
    when(System.getProperty("os.name")).thenReturn("Win");
}
@Test
public void Test2() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
    when(System.getProperty("os.name")).thenReturn("Linux");
}
```

We have two tests method as mentioned above when we are running both the method independently then we are getting correct value of `System.getProperty("os.name")`. But when we are running class (will execute both method in class) then we are getting first method's `System.getProperty("os.name")` value in second method. 
Please suggest.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you add the whole class code ?

Comment: I can't reproduce, please provide the entire test class

Comment: You should definitely wrap `System` in a bridge if you want to test system properties. Think of something like [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/).

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but would you consider wrapping access to system properties in a class? Better design and easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an extra external library, similar to [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/).

You can then achieve your goal by doing the following:

```
public class SystemRulesTest {

  @Rule
  public final RestoreSystemProperties restoreSystemProperties = new RestoreSystemProperties();

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    System.setProperty("os.name", "Win");
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    System.setProperty("os.name", "Linux");
  }
}
```

Note: System Rules requires Junit 4.9 or above to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the system property, why not just `System.setProperty("os.name", "")`? This works:

```
public class SystemPropertyTest {

    @Test
    public void testWin() {
        System.setProperty("os.name", "Win");

        Assert.assertEquals("Win", System.getProperty("os.name"));
    }


    @Test
    public void testLinux() {
        System.setProperty("os.name", "Linux");

        Assert.assertEquals("Linux", System.getProperty("os.name"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Modifying the system properties must be done with a lot of caution or simply avoided as it will affect your env such that it could affect the rest of your tests. At worse you need to re-set the old value at the end of your test.

Comment: Correct, I will modify the answer to include restore of system properties. But that's essentially what PowerMock does, right? Mocking static method will have a global impact. Which is the purpose.

Comment: The point is OP doesn't need static mocking to achieve the goal.